# Determine the number of occurrences of a word in an R array

Tags: r

How would I use R to determine the number of times the word "RED" occurs in the following array:

```
test <- c("RED","WHITE","RED","RED")
```

Comment: `sum(test == "RED")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my answer:

```
sum(test == "RED")
[1] 3
```